# Blind Call Transfer in Asterisk | ari-client (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, asterisk

Precise overview about the flow:

I am calling my initial extension(100) using Zoiper through Twilio sip domain using Zoiper as soft phone which actually direct the call to my asterisk server.

Now when my call is in asterisk server I'm trying to forward it to another extension using Zoiper. I have already configured it according to documentation provided by asterisk will also be attaching the reference links.

**I just want to forward the current call to a particular extension. So please can anyone guide me that how it can be possibly done?**

**ari-client**

```
  bridge.once(‘BridgeAttendedTransfer’, event => {
      var transferee = new ari.Channel(event.transferee.id);
      transferee.continueInDialplan({
            context: event.context,
            extension: event.exten,
            priority: 1
      });
  });
```

**extension.conf**

```
  exten => 201,1,Dial(SIP/201,20,tT)
```

**features.conf**

```
  blindxfer = #2 ("#2" or "##" instead of "#1")
  atxfer = *2 
  
  transferdigittimeout = 1; Number of seconds to wait between digits when transferring a call
  xfersound = beep ; to indicate an attended transfer is complete
  xferfailsound = beeperr ; to indicate a failed transfer
  transferdialattempts = 3 ; Number of times that a transferer may attempt to dial an extension before
  being kicked back to the original call.
  transferretrysound = "beep" ; Sound to play when a transferer fails to dial a valid extension.
  transferinvalidsound = "beeperr" ; Sound to play when a transferer fails to dial a valid extension
```

[**Using Zoiper to make a transfer**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh5s4.png)

**References:**

- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Feature+Code+Call+Transfers
- https://www.aska-ltd.jp/en/blog/185
- https://community.asterisk.org/t/call-transfer-not-working-on-softphones/33817
- https://asteriskfaqs.org/2020/12/22/uncategorized/handling-transfers-with-ari.html

Trying to implement blind call transfer.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to initiate a transfer from your JS code? if so what does your endpoint have to do with it?

Comment: I just want to transfer my current call to another extension through ari-client (node.js) that is the whole objective.

I'm trying different approaches to make it work like I'm using zoiper to call other extension so I could set suitable configuration for blind forwarding.

Comment: If you're trying to implement blind transfer why is ARI code using the `BridgeAttendedTransfer` event?

Comment: I am trying to implement call transfer using ari-client and was using zoiper to make sure its implementable. Now here is the case I'm trying to explain

-We are using Asterisk just as a SIP client, and not as the telephony system that manages the extensions (as that's done on Twilio in our test case). So we have extensions/users 101 and 102 set up on Twilio SIP domain, and when Asterisk is connected to the 101 extension/account I want to forward the call to extension 102 programmatically.

Comment: - And I'm trying it using BridgeAttendedTransfer but I'm not sure with it and I want guidance exactly related to it that how is it possible and what code function and configurations should I use to achieve this transfer case. Hope you understand the case and can guide accordingly. Thanks